# Nexus 7 Android Java VideoView, Can't play this video

Tags: android, android-videoview

i tried to stream a video on my nexus 7 (android 4.2) with the videoview lib, but my nexus 7 displays "Can't play this Video" when i start the app, hope you can help.
my sourcecode:

```
package com.test.prog;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri viduri=Uri.parse("http://www.law.duke.edu/cspd/contest/finalists/viewentry.php?file=docandyou");

        VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        video.setVideoURI(viduri);

    }
}
```

and the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat says:

```
11-19 17:46:08.504: D/VideoView(16804): Error: 1,0
11-19 17:46:19.504: D/MediaPlayer(16804): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
11-19 17:46:19.504: E/MediaPlayer(16804): Unable to to create media player
```

regards
christian

Comment: Android won't play everything. Check http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: i tried much videos with different types but no one works on my nexus 7, did you have a working video sample for videoview?

Comment: I have the same issue on the same device. I've added an onPrepare listener to call VideoView.start and I get audio but no video. Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
`video.start` 
 after you set --> `$`video.setVideoURI(viduri);
```

i can run video on my nexus 7 4.1.2 version with same code of yours